# Creating a schedule on PostInstallHandler on managed package environment

Tags: schedule

I have the following code in PostInstallHandler onInstall function so that when deployment is done the scheduler is created automatically. It works in development environment without any problem however when I create our app as managed package it doesn't work at all. The schedule is registered and can be seen in the schedule log and time is updated, but the ReportCalculation is not get called. What I am doing wrong here?

System.schedule('Report Calculation 1', '0 0 * * * ?', new ReportCalculation());

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue recently. The solution for me involved ensuring **both**:

- the scheduled class is marked `without sharing`
- the post install script is marked `without sharing`

Double check you have indeed designated the `InstallHandler` implementor as a Post Install Script on the package and keep in mind the Post Install user context is **not** the same as the package installer.